# Pointer values in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, syntax

I'm working with OpenGL shaders, which prefer C strings to NSStrings, and I've run into the following oddity:

The relevant facts are that

1) shaderSource is defined as

```
NSString* shaderSource
```

2) the signature of glShaderSource is

```
glShaderSource(GLuint shader, GLuint count, const GLchar** string, const GLint *length)
```

This works:

```
int len = [shaderSource length];
const char *cstr = [shaderSource UTF8String];
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &cstr, &len);
```

This does not work:

```
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &[shaderSource UTF8String], &[shaderSource length]);
```

I am clearly not understanding something about objective c here, and I'd like to rectify that problem, so if you're so inclined, do pray tell, WTF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using `&[shaderSource UTF8String]` to give you an extra level of indirection, so that the types will be correct, since `glShaderSource` wants a pointer to a pointer. But you can't just put `&` in front of anything to get a pointer to it.

`&x` means "return the address of x"; for that to make sense, `x` must be a symbol, not an expression. You can't write `&[shaderSource UTF8String]` for the same reason you can't write `&(1 + t)`. That's just an expression, you need to store the value somewhere, only then you can pass along the address (place where you stored it).

This might be confusing if you are used to C-structs, since if you have a struct `foo` with member `bar`, you *can* get the address of a member by writing `&foo.bar`. But Objective-C objects are not structs (well, technically they are opaque structs). You get property values from them by sending them messages, which is basically the same as a function call. So if `foo` is an object and `bar` is a property, `&foo.bar` (which is really short-hand for `&[foo bar]`) is an invalid expression.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm forgetting my very basic C!  Looks like I'll have to recall it to write  iOS apps.

Comment: In any case, there should be plenty of sample code in the internet for what he wants to achieve (compile a shader from source in NSString)